# Control a subset of the available controls of a USB HID device

Tags: linux, usb, hid

I have a USB HID device which acts as a normal USB HID keyboard. In addition it implements some additional commands (USB HID display).

Is there any way I can write a driver/application to control the display part while leaving the keyboard part up to the kernel/built-in HID drivers?

I already tried to claim the endpoint using libusb. That did not work out as the internal generic USB HID driver already did that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a HID library like [libhid](http://libhid.alioth.debian.org/) to connect to the USB HID driver instead of trying to take over it.